# What is the proper syntax for a SQL CTE in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, common-table-expression

I'm still pretty new to SQL and am trying to use a CTE. My query is not working as intended and I think it's due to the incorrect syntax in this part of the query: `(select "revenue" * 20 from table_name)`. What am I doing wrong?

```
WITH cte_test (country, zipcode, revenue) 
as (
select country, zipcode, revenue+1
from table_name)
select *, (select "revenue" * 20 from table_name)
from cte_test;
```

Comment: How many rows does `table_name` have? If it's more than 1 the query will crash.

Comment: Just replace `*` by `cte_test.*`.

Comment: @TheImpaler, `table_name` has more than one row.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to list the columns for the CTE (although that is allowed).  I would just write this as:

```
WITH cte_test as (
      select country, zipcode, revenue+1 as revenue
      from table_name
     )
select t.*, (select revenue * 20 from table_name)
from cte_test t;
```

Notes:

- I think one problem is the `*` with no table qualification.
- Your subquery will generate a run-time error unless `table_name` has zero or one rows.

Comment: As far as I know, the column list is required in Oracle's CTEs.

Comment: @TheImpaler . . . Not at all:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=60964e899d6d573e779bc235298b0b95.  Well, that is too strong.  I think Oracle requires a column list for recursive CTEs.

Comment: Exactly, Gordon & @TheImpaler; recursive CTEs for newer (11g+) database versions, any CTE for 9iR2 and 10g. There was no CTE in lower version than that.

Comment: `table_name` has more than one row. As you said I received a run-time error. Is there a way around this?

Comment: @GordonLinoff Good distinction. Didn't realize before that non recursive CTEs didn't need the column list.

Comment: @TheImpaler . . . I always make the mistake in the other direction ;)

Comment: Thanks for the help. The following query resolved my issue.

`select revenue * 20
from (select country, zipcode, revenue+1 as revenue
    from table_name) `